# Subgroup generated by a finite family of subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $(H_{i})_{i\in I}$ be a finite family of subgroups of a group $G$. Then

$$\bigvee_{i\in I} H_{i}=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}_{\geq1}}\{y\ |\ (\exists x)(x=(x_i)\in(\cup H_i)^{[1,n]}\ \land y=x_1\dots x_n)\}$$

is the subgroup generated by the family ($H_{i}$).

Under what circumstances, for a $y\in\vee H_i$, can one match the indices of the $(H_i)$ and the $(x_i)$ in a one-to-one manner?

Comment: How did this problem arise?

Comment: I've seen people match them when G is an abelian group; I was wondering how one could generally justify such a move.

Comment: Not sure I understand what you want, do you mean that the decomposition of an element of $\vee H_i$ into a product of elements of the $H_i$ should be unique (the factors are unique, and so is the order)?

Comment: Also, do we agree that $y$ is an element of $G$ here, and not just a string of elements of $H_i$?

Comment: Yes, $y$ is an element of $G$---wouldn't it have to be? With reference to your first comment: I suppose that's one way of expressing my question; but wouldn't that lead us to the construction of the internal direct product?

Comment: I guess, in a way, I am looking to systematically track the "location" of each factor of the decomposition of an element of $\vee H_i$, if that makes sense (with or without tracking the multiplicity).

Comment: Essentially the definition tells you that the elements of the subgroup generated are products of elements of the $H_i$. For abelian groups, you can rearrange this product any way you want, so you can ensure (by adding factors of $e$ if necessary) that there is one and only one factor from each of the subgroups. But if the subgroup generated by the $H_i$ is not abelian, then you will not be able to do so; for by picking two elements that do not commute, $x$ and $y$, the elements $xyx$ will generally not be expressible that way.